# Python tkinter Radio Button Won't Change Variable

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to use radio buttons in python 3.4.3 and the radio buttons are not changing their assigned variable. What am I missing here?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

class c:
def __init__(self):
    self.master=tkinter.Tk()
    self.bvar=IntVar()
    rb1=Radiobutton(self.master,text="1",variable= self.bvar,value=1,command=self.rbselect).pack()
    rb2=Radiobutton(self.master,text="0",variable=self.bvar,value=0,command=self.rbselect).pack()

def rbselect(self):
    print(self.bvar)

def run(self):
    self.master.mainloop()

app=c()
app.run()
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. If you want to print the value you need to print `self.bvar.get()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "not changing their assigned variable", you mean "it always prints `PY_VAR0` no matter which one I select", yes, that is normal behavior - printing an IntVar doesn't give you any information regarding what value it contains. Try using `get` instead.

```
def rbselect(self):
    print(self.bvar.get())
```

Now choosing the "1" radio button causes "1" to be printed, and likewise for "0".

Comment: Thanks, looks like I wasn't understanding the difference between an an intvar and an int

Answer (score 1):

Need to use .get() to compare IntVar instances:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

class c:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master=tkinter.Tk()
        self.b=IntVar() 
        rb1=Radiobutton(self.master,text="1",variable= self.b,value=1,command=self.rbselect).pack()
        rb2=Radiobutton(self.master,text="0",variable= self.b,value=0,command=self.rbselect).pack()

    def rbselect(self):
        print(self.b.get())

    def run(self):
        self.master.mainloop()

app=c()
app.run()
```